# Java ConcurrentSkipListMap ketset to array

Tags: java, toarray, concurrentskiplistmap

I'm trying to use the following line to get an array of the keys from the ConcurrentSkipListMap :

```
myArray=(String[])myMap.keySet().toArray(new String[myMap.size()]);
```

But it didn't work, all the items in the result array are the same, why ?

Comment: How is you map declared, how is myArray declared? What did not work (compiler error? exception?) ? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
myMap.put("a", "b");
myMap.put("b", "c");
String[] myArray= myMap.keySet().toArray(new String[myMap.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

and outputs:

```
[a, b]
```

Note that this is not atomic so if your map is modified between calling `size` and `toArray`, the following would happen:

- if the new map is smaller, `myArray` will have a size that is larger than the array you created in `new String[myMap.size()]`
- if the new map is larger, `myArray` will contain null items

So it probably makes sense to save a call to `size` and avoid a (possibly) unnecessary array creation in this case and simply use:

```
String[] myArray= myMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    ConcurrentSkipListMap myMap = new ConcurrentSkipListMap();
    myMap.put("3", "A");
    myMap.put("2", "B");
    myMap.put("1", "C");
    myMap.put("5", "D");
    myMap.put("4", "E");

    Object[] myArray = myMap.keySet().toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

The result will be:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]